# timer application not running properly

Tags: c#, timer

I am writing a very simple c# application, in which the program counts 15 seconds and outputs "15" as soon as 15 seconds have passed. Although, the program works fine for the first few trials, it starts to freeze instead. Does anyone know why? And how can I improve it?

```
 public void timer()
        {
            time.Text = "restart";
            int i = 0;
            DateTime st1 = DateTime.Now;
            String time1 = st1.Second.ToString();
            int timef = Convert.ToInt32(time1);
            int timef2;

            while (i < 15)
            {

                DateTime st2 = DateTime.Now;
                String time2 = st2.Second.ToString();
                timef2 = Convert.ToInt32(time2);
                i = timef2 - timef;

            }

            time.Text = i.ToString();
            i = 0;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the program doing when it doesn't work?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(15000);` is much easier

Comment: Why don't you use the builtin Timer class?

Comment: Where exactly is the delay of 15 seconds ? I'm only seeing a loop of 15 Steps, not seconds.

Comment: It isn't 15 steps. It is checking the date time and using that to tell time passed.

Comment: So I want to test whether this application outputs 15 at exactly 15 seconds. I want to use this logic in my real application and i'm testing it with this simple method. When it doesn't work, the computer freezes and does nothing.

Comment: @comsfollower this is the wrong way to do your task. NET Framework has many classes to handle timers. You can read about them here http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/all-about-net-timers-comparison.html

Comment: You should just use a timer but if you want to fix code above use date time 1 - date time 2. This will give a timespan. Then check if timespan. Seconds >= 15. If it is then 15 seconds has passed. A timer is a much better option though.

Answer (score 1):

What about making it much simpler if you know about exact 15 seconds!!

```
Thread.Sleep(15000); 
Console.WriteLine("15");
```

Or by going with bulit in timers :-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(15000);
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(T_Elapsed);
            timer.Start();
            var i = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("15");
            var T = (Timer)sender;
            T.Stop;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Timer` if you want your application to perform some actions after specific amount of `time`.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 15 * 1000;
timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
timer.Start();
int timerCount=0;

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 timerCount++;
 int timeElapsed = timerCount * 15;
}
```

Comment: MairajAhmad and @MickyDuncan thank you very much for your help!! Now I'm trying to display the elapsed time on screen? How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can make a variable and whenever timer elapses increment in it. And when you want to display elapsed time multiply that variable by 15. IT will be time in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just use Stopwatch - class that is in System.Diagnostics namespace:

```
    public static void Count()
    {            
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        int i = 0;
        s.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            if (s.ElapsedMilliseconds < i * 1000) { Thread.Sleep(10); continue; }
            i += 15; Console.Write(i + "  "); // or change i to 15 if you want the output to be '15' every time
        }
    }
```